# How to call a non static method of parent class form static method of child class in PHP

Tags: php, class, static

How can i call a non static method of parent class form static method of child class in PHP? Please help.

```
 public static function countryArray(){
    $sql = "SELECT `country_id`, `country_name` FROM `dr_tbl_country`";
    $resultSet  = parent::dBQueryExecute($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($resultSet) > 0){
        $countryArray = array();
        while($result = mysql_fetch_array($resultSet)){
            extract($result);
            $countryArray[$country_id]['country_id'] = $country_id;
            $countryArray[$country_id]['country_name'] = $country_name;
        }
        return $countryArray;       
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you really need to call non-static method from within static method. You probably do not declare your method as `static`. You really don't want `Static` method here

Comment: But i have a situation where i can't instantiate an object of my class.

Comment: OK, i have to find a way around this..

Comment: Yes, drop static. You fooled yourself with static, that is why we normally try to warn early. A workaround is to assign the parent instance to a static class member so that you have got a global variable with a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

You can't; static items work with other static items.

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure that you can't call non-static method from static method (no matter parent or child). That because there is no way to know what instance the non-static method should be called on .... from with in the static method. This should be true for all OOP languages.

Answer (score 1):

In short, **you can't**

You are not able to call a non-`static` method of a parent class from a `static` method of a child class.

Your best option is to make the method non-`static`